# CouchBase features present only on Enteprise version

Tags: couchbase, nosql

While reading the CouchBase Editions [page](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/editions) the following sentence caught my attention:

> Bug fixes and new features are eventually integrated with the Community Edition (CE),but this typically takes several weeks. In addition, Enterprise Edition contains features that are not available in Community Edition. These features are limited to features that support enterprise customers with large production deployments running in data centers and / or public clouds.

What are the feature differences between enterprise and community editions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to Couchbase Server 2.2.0 there are no differences in features between the community and enterprise editions.

As of version 2.5 there will be some feature only available in Enterprise Edition:

- Rack Awareness
- XDCR data security

This is noted in the 2.5.0 [release notes](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-release-notes/#enhancements-in-25).

Couchbase have not released version 2.5 Community Edition yet.

Comment: Will these features be available in community 2.5 or still be restricted ? I couldn't find a clear answer in the linked release notes.